# Is there a way of dynamically generating type hints for reflected code in mypy or pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, mypy

I am writing a utility which uses reflection quite heavily. For example, taking any random dataclass...

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    title: str
```

I can run something like the following...

```
condition_filter = condition(Foo).title.like('bar')
```

The call to `condition` actually dynamically generates a new type at runtime with a signature based on the given input. The result is like the following...

```
class FooCondition:
    title: StrCondition
```

(Where StrCondition has the `like` method which is called to return some actual condition.)

Is there a way to also specify type hints for the generated `FooCondition` along with the class, so that my IDE / mypy can offer reasonable code completion / type checking?

Comment: You can write a `mypy` plugin for this purpose (probably with `get_dynamic_class_hook`). It will take a lot of efforts, though, and will require end users to install this plugin. I doubt the same is possible for IDE.